# How to set timezone to UTC in Apache Spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, jvm

In Spark's WebUI (port 8080) and on the environment tab there is a setting of the below:

```
user.timezone   Zulu
```

Do you know how/where I can override this to UTC?

Env details:

- Spark 2.1.1
- jre-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64
- no jdk
- EC2 Amazon Linux

Comment: so, as per the link in the deleted answer, the Zulu TZ has 0 offset from UTC, which means for most practical purposes you wouldn't need to change.

Answer (score -25, accepted):

Change your system timezone and check it I hope it will works

Comment: This does not really solve the problem. One can not change the TZ on all systems used.

Answer (score 47):

Now you can use:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "UTC")
```

Since https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18936 in 2.2.0

Additionally, I set my default TimeZone to UTC to avoid implicit conversions

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
```

Otherwise you will get implicit conversions from your default Timezone to UTC when no Timezone information is present in the Timestamp you're converting

Example:

```
val rawJson = """ {"some_date_field": "2018-09-14 16:05:37"} """

val dsRaw = sparkJob.spark.createDataset(Seq(rawJson))

val output =
  dsRaw
    .select(
      from_json(
        col("value"),
        new StructType(
          Array(
            StructField("some_date_field", DataTypes.TimestampType)
          )
        )
      ).as("parsed")
    ).select("parsed.*")
```

If my default TimeZone is Europe/Dublin which is GMT+1 and Spark sql session timezone is set to UTC, Spark will assume that "2018-09-14 16:05:37" is in Europe/Dublin TimeZone and do a conversion (result will be "2018-09-14 15:05:37")

Comment: You will need to `import java.util.TimeZone` to set the default timezone as suggested here.

Answer (score 25):

In some cases you will also want to set the JVM timezone. For example, when loading data into a TimestampType column, it will interpret the string in the local JVM timezone. To set the JVM timezone you will need to add extra [JVM options](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/configuration.html#runtime-environment) for the driver and executor:

```
spark = pyspark.sql.SparkSession \
    .Builder()\
    .appName('test') \
    .master('local') \
    .config('spark.driver.extraJavaOptions', '-Duser.timezone=GMT') \
    .config('spark.executor.extraJavaOptions', '-Duser.timezone=GMT') \
    .config('spark.sql.session.timeZone', 'UTC') \
    .getOrCreate()
```

We do this in our local unit test environment, since our local time is not GMT.

Useful reference:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

Comment: Love this answer for 2 reasons. #1) it sets the config on the session builder instead of a the session. This doesn't make a difference for timezone due to the order in which you're executing (all spark code runs AFTER a session is created usually before your config is set). #2) This is the only answer that correctly suggests the setting of the user timezone in JVM and the reason to do so! Wish the OP would accept this answer :(

Comment: seealso: https://databricks.com/blog/2020/07/22/a-comprehensive-look-at-dates-and-timestamps-in-apache-spark-3-0.html

Answer (score 6):

As described in these SPARK bug reports ([link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-33150), [link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-32123)), the most current SPARK versions (3.0.0 and 2.4.6 at time of writing) do not fully/correctly support setting the timezone for all operations, despite the answers by @Moemars and @Daniel.

I suggest avoiding time operations in SPARK as much as possible, and either perform them yourself after extraction from SPARK or by using UDFs, as used in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53763643/timezone-conversion-with-pyspark-from-timestamp-and-country).

Answer (score 0):

You can use below to set the time zone to any zone you want and your notebook or session will keep that value for `current_time()` or `current_timestamp()`.

```sql
%sql
SET TIME ZONE 'America/**Los_Angeles**' - >  To get PST
SET TIME ZONE 'America/**Chicago**';  - >   To get CST
```

The last part should be a city , its not allowing all the cities as far as I tried.

Referenece : https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-aux-conf-mgmt-set-timezone.html