# Spark convert timestamps from CSV into Parquet "local time" semantics

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

Consider this minimal Spark job that reads a CSV to a DataFrame and and writes it out as Parquet:

```
val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("inferSchema", true).load(filename)
df.write.parquet("parquet_folder/")
```

For any timestamp columns in the input file, the Parquet output will contain a timestamp, with *instant* semantics, interpreting the time string in the source data in the current Spark session/JVM timezone.  So "2020-01-01 00:00" becomes "2020-01-01 00:00-0500" if my Spark job is running in EST/EDT.

This means, I could have discrepancies unless all Spark jobs run in a single consistent timezone.

There is also a theoretical problem which is that the Parquet doesn't actually represent my data.  I don't know whether the midnight in the file is really midnight EST, PST, UTC, etc., and I don't really care.

The Parquet format does support the concept of timestamps with *local time* semantics analogous to `java.util.LocalDateTime` -- an abstract concept of date/time, not a specific moment in time, which would be interpreted consistently regardless of the Spark session's or JVM's time zone.

What I would like is for Spark to read timestamps from CSV into local times, that get written to Parquet accordingly.  Ideally I would like to apply the same to Spark JDBC extraction as well, from date and "timestamp without time zone" columns.

Is this even possible?

(Note: [The Parquet format documentation](https://github.com/apache/parquet-format/blob/master/LogicalTypes.md) explains the distinction between instant semantics and local time semantics.)

Comment: Feature request in Spark: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-28955

Comment: _maybe_ this will be addressed in Spark 3.3.0?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue. Spark timestamp conversion can be confusing.

To make spark jobs robust against the default local timezone settings of any hosting machine, add an extra layer to temporarily and explicitly set the spark time zone:

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

@contextmanager
def spark_timezone(timezone: str):
    """Context manager to temporarily set spark timezone during context manager
    life time while preserving original timezone. This is especially
    meaningful in conjunction with casting timestamps when automatic timezone
    conversions are applied by spark.

    Please be aware that the timezone property should be adjusted during DAG
    creation and execution (including both spark transformations and actions).
    Changing the timezone while adding filter/map tasks might not be
    sufficient. Be sure to change the timezone when actually executing a spark
    action like collect/save etc.

    Parameters
    ----------
    timezone: str
        Name of the timezone (e.g. 'UTC' or 'Europe/Berlin').

    Examples
    --------
    >>> with spark_timezone("Europe/Berlin"):
    >>>     df.select(df["ts_col"].cast("timestamp")).show()

    """

    spark = get_active_spark_context()
    current = spark.conf.get("spark.sql.session.timeZone")
    spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", timezone)

    try:
        yield None
    finally:
        spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", current)


def get_active_spark_context() -> SparkSession:
    """Helper function to return the currently active spark context.

    """

    return SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
```

Now, you can wrap your `spark.read.csv` via the context manager with explicit UTC timezone to prevent any conversion:

```py
with spark_timezone("UTC"):
    df = spark.read.csv("path_to_file")
```

### Update 2022-01-31

Just came across this issue once again while reading a CSV file containing timestamp columns. The timestamp columns will be interpreted in local timezone regardless of whether you set spark's timezone explicitly or not.

Spark's timezone does not take affect for converting string to timestamp within the JVM. Instead, you need to modify JVMs timezone settings, as described in this SO [article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60922147/7366928).