# Writing Spark Dataframe to ORC gives the wrong timezone

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, timezone, orc

Whenever I write a Dataframe into ORC, the timezone of Timestamp fields is not correct.
here's my code -

```
// setting the timezone

val schema = List(
  StructField("name", StringType),
  StructField("date", TimestampType)
  )

val data = Seq(
  Row("test", java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf("2021-03-15 10:10:10.0"))
  )

val df = spark.createDataFrame(
  spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data),
  StructType(schema)
  )

// changing the timezone
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "MDT")

// value of the df has changed accordingly
df.show // prints 2021-03-15 08:10:10

// writing to orc
df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).format("orc").save("/tmp/dateTest.orc/")
```

value in ORC file will be 2021-03-15 10:10:10.0.

Is there any way to control the writer's timezone? am i missing something here?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you know that the value in the ORC file is `10:10:10`? Did you read it using Spark or other things?

Comment: @mck opened it using orc-tools

Comment: You might want to change the JVM timezone to MDT. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60922147/14165730)

Comment: @mck tried it, but it did not help.. tried setting all these params and writing. then i tried recreating the HiveContext, but also got the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after much investigation, this is something that's not supported (ATM) for ORC. it is supported for csv, though.