# spark sql to read time zone date

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am getting date and time in EDT format something like

```
"May 15 2022 23:29:08.607 EDT"
```

I want to convert  that date time into unix_time so I am trying

```
spark.sql("""select unix_time (May 15 2022 23:29:08.607 EDT, "MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss") as new_date from table """)
```

What I need to mention in time format so that spark will know the input date in EDT timezone ,
I tried  something as MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz but it did not help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SET TIME ZONE`. see [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-aux-conf-mgmt-set-timezone.html).
See also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49644232/how-to-set-timezone-to-utc-in-apache-spark)

To specify the time zone as part of the query you can use `to_utc_timestamp` [function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.to_utc_timestamp.html)

Comment: cant we have any option in spark.sql itself

Comment: you can set the following parameter `spark.sql.session.timeZone`

Comment: @punam sorry, I didn't understood what you meant.
You have the `to_utc_timestamp` [function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.to_utc_timestamp.html) where you can specify the timezone as part of the query

Comment: I want given date into UTC time ,  so I am using unix_time (May 15 2022 23:29:08.607 EDT, "MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss") but here I did not mentioned timezone , how to add timezone ,can we inform spark that given time is in EDT format