# Error in converting spark dataframe to pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I am using an external jar on my spark cluster to load a `DataFrame`. I am getting an error in attempting to convert this `DataFrame` to a pandas `DataFrame`.
The code is as follows :

```
jvm = spark._jvm
gateway = jvm.com.<external.package.classname>

data_w = gateway.loadData()

df = DataFrame(data_w, spark)
pandas_df = df.toPandas()
```

The spark dataframe `df` has valid data. However I am getting an error in the pandas conversion

```
File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/pandas/conversion.py", line 67, in toPandas
'RuntimeConfig' object has no attribute 'sessionLocalTimeZone'
```

The spark dataframe has 2 date columns. Is there any `jconf` settings I need to add on my spark context for conversion ?

I can see https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/pandas/conversion.html that there is a usage of `sessionLocalTimeZone`. Do we need to explicitly set this on spark `jconf`. I am not setting this locally and it works fine.

Comment: not entirely sure, but this might be asking for the spark session's conf which can be set using `spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "UTC")` (change UTC to preferred tz). also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60922147/8279585)

Comment: This config did not help.