# How to cast Date column from string to datetime in pyspark/python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark-pandas

I have a date column with string datatype when inferred in pyspark:

```
Mon Oct 17 15:57:48 EST 2022
```

How to cast string datatype as datetime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the required [datetime formatters](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html) - `'E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy'`. the resulting timestamp will be in UTC and, thus, you'll see that it will [add 5 hours](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/est#:%7E:text=Eastern%20Standard%20Time%20(EST)%20is,America%2C%20Caribbean%2C%20Central%20America.) to the source ts.

```py
spark.conf.set('spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy', 'LEGACY')

spark.sparkContext.parallelize([('Mon Oct 17 15:57:48 EST 2022', )]).toDF(['dt_str']). \
    withColumn('dt', func.to_timestamp('dt_str', 'E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy')). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +----------------------------+-------------------+
# |dt_str                      |dt                 |
# +----------------------------+-------------------+
# |Mon Oct 17 15:57:48 EST 2022|2022-10-17 20:57:48|
# +----------------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your input!. I'm trying to convert to datetime instead of timestamp. Is it possible? Because when I try to convert, it is showing as not supported.

Comment: @Anos - datetime means timestamp. do you mean just the date part? use the `to_date` function instead of `to_timestamp`.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I thought we have separate datetime datatype conversion. So, I get to know datetime ideally means timestamp datatype. Thanks!

Comment: When I try to convert this Wed Oct 19 00:15:13 EST 2022, the resulting timestamp is 2022-10-19 10:45:13. Not really getting what is happening. It is not adding +5

Comment: @Anos - it must be because your default tz is set to be something other than UTC, and spark is adding the offset based on that tz. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49644232/8279585) to reset your session's tz