# Extract date from pySpark timestamp column (no UTC timezone) in Palantir

Tags: date, pyspark, timestamp, timezone, palantir-foundry

I have a timestamp of this type: 2022-11-09T23:19:32.000Z

When I cast to date, my output is "2022-11-10" but I wanna "2022-11-09". Is there a way to force utc 0 (not +1) or extract directly data with a regex to bring only date without consider timezone?

I have tried also substring('2022-11-09T23:19:32.000Z', 1, 10) or some function to extract string... but my output is the same: "2022-11-10".

Example:

`Input`

| id | start_date |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 2020-04-10T23:55:19.000Z |

My code:

```
df_output = df_input.withColumn('date', F.regex_extract(F.col('start_date', '(\\d{4})-(\\d{2})-(\\d{2})', 0))
```

`Wrong Output`

| id | start_date | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2020-04-10T23:55:19.000Z | 2020-04-11 |

---

`Desidered Output [I wanna extract string from timestamp without consider timezone]`

| id | start_date | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2020-04-10T23:55:19.000Z | 2020-04-10 |

Comment: what is your session's and database's timezone? see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49644232/8279585)

Comment: any chance you are in an on prem stack with server clock on a different timezone?

Comment: I am in europe, Austria. I think timestamp is setted on UTC but the question is relative. Is it possible that there is no way to extract a string regardless of the timezone of the date? That is, I would like to extract the first 10 characters (2022-04-10) without considering that they have to change according to the timezone.

Comment: spark stores date/time as bigint which is tz-less -- number of seconds from Jan'70 UTC. so, whatever is happening has to do with your server's setting, as it sees the input as of a different tz and offsets it. btw, have you tried setting `spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "UTC")` before your operations?

Comment: yes I've tried it but doesn't work... Do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your spark timezone must be configured to something other than UTC.

Any kind of conversion on the timestamp gives you the local date.

You can adjust your timezone for the session:

```py
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "UTC")
df = df.withColumn('date_utc', F.to_date('start_date'))
```

Or you can subtract the timezone offset, so that it behaves like UTC:

```py
tz = spark.conf.get("spark.sql.session.timeZone")
df = df.withColumn('date_utc', F.to_date(F.to_utc_timestamp('start_date', tz)))
```

Answer (score -1):

Can't you use the [to_date](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.to_date.html) function? This here works for me:

```
from datetime import datetime

from pyspark.sql.functions import to_date
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, TimestampType

    df = spark.createDataFrame(
        [
            (
                "123",
                datetime.strptime("2020-04-10T23:55:19.000Z", '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
            )
        ],
        StructType([
            StructField("id", StringType()),
            StructField("start_date", TimestampType()),
        ]))
    
    df.withColumn("date", to_date("start_date", "%Y-%m-%d")).show()
```

**Output:**

```
+---+-------------------+----------+
| id|         start_date|      date|
+---+-------------------+----------+
|123|2020-04-10 23:55:19|2020-04-10|
+---+-------------------+----------+
```

Comment: For me is 2020-04-11! It's unbielievable!! I'm losing hope