# spark.createDataFrame() changes the date value in column with type datetime64[ns, UTC]

Tags: pandas, pyspark, python-3.8, python-datetime

I am currently having a weird problem when using `pySpark` in Pycharm 2021 (my Python's version is `3.8.5`). The line that caused trouble was `spark.createDataFrame(df)` to create a Spark dataframe where `df` is a `dataframe` object that has a column `date` with `dtype = datetime64[ns, UTC]`. I created a Spark data-frame successfully, however the outputs returned from the `date` column are **incorrect**, because they **changed**. Originally, `df` has `date` values ranging from `2022-10-01` to `2022-10-31` (i.e., every days in October 2022). After being put into `spark.createDataFrame()`, the resulting `date` column has values from `2022-09-30` to `2022-10-30.`

I inspected the root cause of this, and the only thing I could see that **potentially** causes this weird behavior is about the `dtype` of `date` column in `df`, which is `datetime64[ns, UTC]` object, while the resulting `date` column from `spark.createDataFrame(df)` is of `timestamp`.

**Question.** Does anyone know how to overcome this weird behavior? Would this behavior be eliminated if we somehow were able to convert the column `date` with `dtype = datetime64[ns, UTC]` to `dtype = timestamp` in `df`?

**Sample Data.**

```
start = Timestamp('2022-10-01 00:00:00+0000', tz='UTC', freq='MS')
def feat(start):
    end = start + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0)
    end = end.to_pydatetime()
    dates = pd.date_range(start, end, freq='D')
    return pd.DataFrame({
        'date': dates,
        'year': dates.year,
        'month': dates.month,
        'weekday': dates.dayofweek,
    })
df = feat(start) 
df_dates = spark.createDataFrame(df)
df_dates.select('date').show(31) ---- Output the result for inspection!
```

**Sample Output.**

```
feat(start) 

         date                 year  month  weekday
0  2022-10-01 00:00:00+00:00  2022     10    5             
1  2022-10-02 00:00:00+00:00  2022     10    6             
2  2022-10-03 00:00:00+00:00  2022     10    0             
3  2022-10-04 00:00:00+00:00  2022     10    1             
4  2022-10-05 00:00:00+00:00  2022     10    2             
5  2022-10-06 00:00:00+00:00  2022     10    3             
6  2022-10-07 00:00:00+00:00  2022     10    4             
7  2022-10-08 00:00:00+00:00  2022     10    5             
8  2022-10-09 00:00:00+00:00  2022     10    6             
9  2022-10-10 00:00:00+00:00  2022     10    0             
10 2022-10-11 00:00:00+00:00  2022     10    1             
11 2022-10-12 00:00:00+00:00  2022     10    2             
12 2022-10-13 00:00:00+00:00  2022     10    3             
13 2022-10-14 00:00:00+00:00  2022     10    4             
14 2022-10-15 00:00:00+00:00  2022     10    5             
15 2022-10-16 00:00:00+00:00  2022     10    6             
16 2022-10-17 00:00:00+00:00  2022     10    0             
17 2022-10-18 00:00:00+00:00  2022     10    1             
18 2022-10-19 00:00:00+00:00  2022     10    2             
19 2022-10-20 00:00:00+00:00  2022     10    3             
20 2022-10-21 00:00:00+00:00  2022     10    4             
21 2022-10-22 00:00:00+00:00  2022     10    5             
22 2022-10-23 00:00:00+00:00  2022     10    6             
23 2022-10-24 00:00:00+00:00  2022     10    0             
24 2022-10-25 00:00:00+00:00  2022     10    1             
25 2022-10-26 00:00:00+00:00  2022     10    2             
26 2022-10-27 00:00:00+00:00  2022     10    3             
27 2022-10-28 00:00:00+00:00  2022     10    4            
28 2022-10-29 00:00:00+00:00  2022     10    5          
29 2022-10-30 00:00:00+00:00  2022     10    6           
30 2022-10-31 00:00:00+00:00  2022     10    0
```

`df_dates.select('date').show(31)`

```
|               date|
+-------------------+
|2022-09-30 20:00:00|
|2022-10-01 20:00:00|
|2022-10-02 20:00:00|
|2022-10-03 20:00:00|
|2022-10-04 20:00:00|
|2022-10-05 20:00:00|
|2022-10-06 20:00:00|
|2022-10-07 20:00:00|
|2022-10-08 20:00:00|
|2022-10-09 20:00:00|
|2022-10-10 20:00:00|
|2022-10-11 20:00:00|
|2022-10-12 20:00:00|
|2022-10-13 20:00:00|
|2022-10-14 20:00:00|
|2022-10-15 20:00:00|
|2022-10-16 20:00:00|
|2022-10-17 20:00:00|
|2022-10-18 20:00:00|
|2022-10-19 20:00:00|
|2022-10-20 20:00:00|
|2022-10-21 20:00:00|
|2022-10-22 20:00:00|
|2022-10-23 20:00:00|
|2022-10-24 20:00:00|
|2022-10-25 20:00:00|
|2022-10-26 20:00:00|
|2022-10-27 20:00:00|
|2022-10-28 20:00:00|
|2022-10-29 20:00:00|
|2022-10-30 20:00:00|
```

**Caveat.** When I tried exporting the `feat(start)` to a `.csv` file and read it back with `x=pd.read_csv([directory path of .csv file here])` function, and then proceed with `spark.createDataFrame(x)`, the result was correct. Inspecting the `dtype` of `date` column of `x`, it is of type `object`.

Comment: Which timezone your original string/text dates are in?

Comment: @AzharKhan The timestamp above was in `UTC` timezone (you can see the parameter `tz = UTC.`) All the values under `date` column of `feat(start)` was also in `UTC`.

Comment: Nobody has encountered this problem before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dates are in desired "UTC" format; but possibly it is the toString() or show() which is converting it to your local timezone or the timezone your Spark's driver/worker machine is running on.

If you notice the time part in the printed timestamp, it is 8PM (2022-09-30 **20:00:00**), which suggests that your Spark driver/worker machine is in "UTC-4" ("Canada Eastern" or "USA EST") timezone.

You can verify it by rendering the given dates in UTC and EST using [from_utc_timestamp](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.from_utc_timestamp.html#pyspark.sql.functions.from_utc_timestamp):

```py
df_dates.select(
    F.from_utc_timestamp(df_dates.date, "Canada/Eastern").alias("EST"),
    F.from_utc_timestamp(df_dates.date, "UTC").alias("UTC")
    ).show(31)
```

Output:

```
+-------------------+-------------------+
|                EST|                UTC|
+-------------------+-------------------+
|2022-09-30 20:00:00|2022-10-01 00:00:00|
|2022-10-01 20:00:00|2022-10-02 00:00:00|
|2022-10-02 20:00:00|2022-10-03 00:00:00|
|2022-10-03 20:00:00|2022-10-04 00:00:00|
|2022-10-04 20:00:00|2022-10-05 00:00:00|
|2022-10-05 20:00:00|2022-10-06 00:00:00|
|2022-10-06 20:00:00|2022-10-07 00:00:00|
|2022-10-07 20:00:00|2022-10-08 00:00:00|
|2022-10-08 20:00:00|2022-10-09 00:00:00|
|2022-10-09 20:00:00|2022-10-10 00:00:00|
|2022-10-10 20:00:00|2022-10-11 00:00:00|
|2022-10-11 20:00:00|2022-10-12 00:00:00|
|2022-10-12 20:00:00|2022-10-13 00:00:00|
|2022-10-13 20:00:00|2022-10-14 00:00:00|
|2022-10-14 20:00:00|2022-10-15 00:00:00|
|2022-10-15 20:00:00|2022-10-16 00:00:00|
|2022-10-16 20:00:00|2022-10-17 00:00:00|
|2022-10-17 20:00:00|2022-10-18 00:00:00|
|2022-10-18 20:00:00|2022-10-19 00:00:00|
|2022-10-19 20:00:00|2022-10-20 00:00:00|
|2022-10-20 20:00:00|2022-10-21 00:00:00|
|2022-10-21 20:00:00|2022-10-22 00:00:00|
|2022-10-22 20:00:00|2022-10-23 00:00:00|
|2022-10-23 20:00:00|2022-10-24 00:00:00|
|2022-10-24 20:00:00|2022-10-25 00:00:00|
|2022-10-25 20:00:00|2022-10-26 00:00:00|
|2022-10-26 20:00:00|2022-10-27 00:00:00|
|2022-10-27 20:00:00|2022-10-28 00:00:00|
|2022-10-28 20:00:00|2022-10-29 00:00:00|
|2022-10-29 20:00:00|2022-10-30 00:00:00|
|2022-10-30 20:00:00|2022-10-31 00:00:00|
+-------------------+-------------------+
```

I scanned through Spark's date and timestamp source code; but I am sorry I could not find any evidence to support my statement above. The link to the toString() implementation is missing: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.types.TimestampType.html#pyspark.sql.types.TimestampType.simpleString

Comment: Excellent finding. Thank you so much for your great help. Do you happen to know if there is a way for me to set the timezone of Spark driver to be in 'UTC' rather than 'EST' with Pyspark?

Comment: I have not tried this; but please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49644232/how-to-set-timezone-to-utc-in-apache-spark